# Bulk Insert-Wide Native syntax

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a script so I can Bulk Load (SQL Server) an entire database of tables previously exported via BCP.

Currently I have:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF --original
select 'BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..' + name + '" FROM ' + name + '.txt ' 
from sysobjects where type = 'U' order by name
```

which returns:

```
BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..DBA_INDEXS" FROM DBA_INDEXS.txt 
BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..PSACCESSLOG" FROM PSACCESSLOG.txt 
BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..PSACCESSPRFL" FROM PSACCESSPRFL.txt 
BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..PSACTARCHIVE" FROM PSACTARCHIVE.txt 
BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..PSACTIVEXLIC" FROM PSACTIVEXLIC.txt
```

I need to add two more command (Wide Native and path to BCP files) to the script at the top.
This command below is what will build the Bulk Insert on one table:

```
BULK INSERT HRPXXXB.dbo.TABLE1 FROM 'K:\SQL_Backup\BCP\HRPXXX_TABLE1.txt'  WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE   = 'widenative')
```

Appreciate replies

Comment: thanks, I just made a modification---SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
select 'BULK INSERT EP88XXX..' + name + ' FROM "E:\EP88XXX_BCP_Test3\' + name + '.txt"
WITH  (DATAFILETYPE =''widenative'')'  from sysobjects where type = 'U' 
order by name ....but single quotes around path are needed as double quotes around path will not locate files.  I replaced double quotes on path statement with single but have syntax issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 'BULK INSERT "EP88XXX..' + name + '" FROM ' + name + '.txt 
WITH  ( DATAFILETYPE   = ''widenative'')"'  from sysobjects where type = 'U' 
order by name
```

Comment: I just reworked it and used two single quotes and managed to run script and bulk load statement successfully...SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
select 'BULK INSERT EP88XXX..' + name + ' FROM ''E:\EP88XXX_BCP_Test3\' + name + '.txt''
WITH  (DATAFILETYPE =''widenative'')'  from sysobjects where type = 'U' 
order by name

Comment: Ok. You may need to accept this as answer so that others know that this is answered :)